# how to use qtip directive in angular2 app

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, qtip2

I have full calendar in angular app, I am looking for qtip2 tooltips for calendar events. I have installed qtip2 and jquery and have included `<a href="/cool-stuff" qtip="Text to appear in the tip">Hover me</a>`  in my calendar.component.ts for testing purpose of tooltip. But when i hover over this no tooltips displays on hovering over the " Hover me". I am not sure what i am missing so my tooltips displays on the screen. any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: AFAIK you have to actually initialise the qtip on an element using Javascript? Check the qtip docs for examples.

Comment: @ADyson here i am initialising qtip on element with anchor tag in javascript only  <a href="/cool-stuff" qtip="Text to appear in the tip">Hover me</a>? do you mean anyhting else?

Comment: " in javascript only"....but `<a href="/cool-stuff" qtip="Text to appear in the tip">Hover me</a>` is not Javascript, it's HTML.

Comment: eventRender: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        
        $('.tooltip').qtip({
    content: {
        text: calEvent.title
            
        }
    }
})

Comment: @ADyson do you mean above lines of js code. I am using it in eventRender function to show qtips but no help!!

Comment: The HTML and the JS appear unrelated. Do you have any elements with the class "tooltip" defined? Your href does not have that class. Also, even if it did, it would not end up with the same title as defined in the "qtip" attribute you gave to the element (it would get the calendar event's title instead).

Comment: @ADyson i did made changes  
eventRender: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { $('.tooltip').qtip({ content: { text: qtip.title } } })  and html code <a class="tooltip" href="/cool-stuff" qtip="Text to appear in the tip">Hover me</a> still doesnt work

Comment: `qtip.title` looks wrong. You have a JS variable called "qtip" or not? I would guess not.

Comment: @ADyson ok got it, i would like to show  calendar event's title instead with { content: { text: calEvent.title } } , then also it does not work?

Comment: Where are you adding this `<a href` exactly in the page? In the simple example given in the fullCalendar docs (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) the qtip is applied to the `element` variable which represents the HTML for the event. That way the tooltip then appears next to the event itself. You don't need any extra HTML elements for that. Your definition of EventRender as `function(calEvent, jsEvent, view)` is wrong, the docs clearly show the the callback should be defined as `function(event, element, view) {`). I don't know where you got your version from

Comment: @ADyson - the definition of eventRender in angular2 typescript is function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) not function(event, element, view). i have checked it.  in typescript calEvent holds the calendar event data and jsEvent is the elemnet to be rendered. its not my own version, plz check.

Comment: well it probably makes no difference because JS is not strongly typed or anything, but the wording is misleading - a Javascript (js) event is not an (html) element. They obviously copied wrongly from fullCalendar's definition when creating their angular layer. There are other fullCalendar callbacks which do have that signature such as https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/ - where the 2nd argument really is a javascript event object). You can change the names to whatever you like, though. `function(sadfsg, rrrttt, zheskjh)` will behave identically, it's just confusing to the reader.

Comment: anyway, in your version `function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { jsEvent.qtip({ content: { text: calEvent.title } } }` would be logical (where jsEvent is really a jquery HTML element despite the parameter name, as explained above) to define the tooltip and attach it to the event HTML. And you wouldn't need your extra `<a href` bit

Comment: @ADyson i have written the code with function(event, element, view) {} what doc syays still doesn't work. I think using fullcalendar in angular2 application and im trying to call qtips on top of this, these things making it painful to work together, i tried to search but no help found.

Comment: "not working" how? Just nothing happens, or some problem? Any errors in your browser console? Perhaps you can make a working demo that shows the problem, either using the Snippet feature here, or a sandbox site like JSFiddle? Then we can see the issue up close.

Comment: @ADyson Please have a look at this plunkr code. I have added qtip2 library to it. still it does not render any tip. [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/1b5AovrNwd08eEa6YAzh?p=preview)

Comment: where to start? You include the qtip JS twice, the qtip CSS 4 times, jquery twice, momentJS twice, fullCalendar twice. You define eventRender twice (and a third time commented out). Nowhere do you actually apply any qtip to anything (apart from in the commented out bit). The whole thing is a total mess and needs junking and starting again instead of fixing it. I'm surprised _any_ of it works, tbh. Sort the fundamental setup of your app out before worrying about details like tooltips.

Comment: @ADyson i have cleaned and updated the plunker. plz have look.  [link code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z9KncHgpXqHSO7YslrRJ?p=preview)